# Mongoose await for node.js req.query data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on small backend project. I send GET requests via postman to **express.js** app. Express send request to **mongoose** and return data.

I am trying to make it shorter by writing req.query.data instead of object name.
**req.query.data** is object name which is imported to node file but **mongoose "find"** function read it as "req.query.data" instead of acuall data.

I tried putting req data in () but it still didn't want to read value. I have no idea how to make it working

Code:

```js
const Daily = require("./DailyStats/DailySchema")

module.exports.GetData = async (req, res) => {


    await Daily.find({"Date.month": 3}, function (err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.error(err)
        }
        res.send(data)
    })


}
```

What I want is

```js
    await (req.query.data).find({"Date.month": 3}, function (err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.error(err)
        }
        res.send(data)
    })
```

While using second code I got error "Cannot use method find on req.query.data"

Comment: Share some code. Let's take a look at you've got.

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: @Brettski Thx 4 tip. Already updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find should be called on a `mongoose.Model`

You may use `mongoose.model(req.query.data)` assuming req.query.data is your model name

That said you should

- check that provided data is only a valid model name
- name data better, like modelName

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dummy')
const NameModel = mongoose.model('Name', { name:String }, 'names')

;(async()=>{
  try {
  console.log(mongoose.model('Name') === NameModel) // true
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }
})()
```

Comment: After doing what you wrote
let model = mongoose.model(req.query.type, req.query.type) where req.query.type is "DailySchema" which is imported to that file as "Daily", I get: 
"MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Daily".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)"
Where I did pass schema before in "Model"

let model = mongoose.model(req.query.type, req.query.type)
model.find()

Comment: You should not give a schema but a modelName (a string).
You get a mongoose.Model by declaring **ONCE**
```mongoose.model('MODELNAME', schema, mongodbCollectionName)``` (cf third line of my sample code)
In your case somewhere you should have written ```mongoose.model('Daily', DailySchema, 'dailies')```
In which case you want ```req.query.data``` to be ```'Daily'```, and use ```mongoose.model(req.query.data)```

Comment: "Model name ( a string )". I know that but I got value inside of variable and I am trying to add variable INSTEAD of string and add ".find()" method on it. 
I know that I can write "Daily"
Req.query.type is data which I receive from "GET" request send by frontend. I want to paste it as variable and use ".find()" method on it

Comment: does ```req.query.type``` holds the model name as value ?
Either you can do as I proposed, either you may find a way to retrieve the associated model (either a good old switch, either a map: ```m={daily: DailyModel, weekly: WeeklyModel}; m[req.query.data].find()``` )